# Special template method call syntax

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I recently encountered the following C++ syntax:

```
int a = MyObj.template MyMethod<MyType>();
```

Is there a name for this sort of syntax? Where can I read more about when it is required?

This is opposed to the usual syntax which is just

```
int a = MyObj.MyMethod<MyType>();
```

The first syntax form seems to be required in some cases where the called method has both template and non-template overloads; the regular form of just calling the function gave an error in the code I compiled with clang.

Comment: You're looking for "dependent names".